# Associate ready annotations with a raw PDF file with Okular

Tags: kde, pdf, ntfs, testdisk, okular

## Problem

Accidently, the file `x.pdf` which was a book with a lot of annotations created by `Okular` is deleted. Annotations, however, are present in `/home/user/.var/app/org.kde.okular/data/okular/docdata/`. I have the raw file (annotation-less file) of `x.pdf`.

## Question

How to associate existing annotations with the raw `x.pdf`?

## Problem Details

Actually I didn't delete the file myself; I was reading the book, I added some annotations as usual; when I wanted to save the changes, `Okular` hanged up; I closed it, then the file was not there in its directory....it got completely disappeared.

## Tested Workarounds

I have used `testdisk`; it doesn't found anything as my partition is `NTFS`. Therefore I used `ntfsundelete` which also was unsuccessfull, i.e. it didn't find my deleted file.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is going to get a lot of downvotes, but

Isn't it easier to restore files with TestDisk?

Comment: I have tested `testdisk`; it doesn't found anything as my partition is `NTFS`. Therefore I used `ntfsundelete` which also was unsuccessfull, i.e. it didn't find my deleted file.

Comment: Actually I didn't delete the file myself; I was reading the book, I added some annotations as usual, when I wanted to save the changes, `Okular` hanged up; I closed it, then the file was not there in its directory....it got completely disappeared.